# Remove Grub Rescue and boot straight to Windows 10

Tags: boot, windows-10, grub, rescue

I installed Kali alongside my Windows10. I decided to uninstall Kali, so deleted the partitions and used EasyBCD to restore back to Windows MBR. Upon boot Grub rescue still loads. So I ran a live Ubuntu and ran boot-repair which also didn't remove Grub rescue. Im wondering if I have any other options to try to remove Grub rescue, or a link to a guide would be handy. Bottom of my post has Boot-repair report

Windows boots as EUFI, I can toggle this to secure and it boots straight to Windows. But Id rather know how to have a clean MBR with no Grub rescue

Ubuntu Pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/15399387/ (My Windows 10 is on SSD and has 7 partitions)

Paste from boot-repair at Wed, 16 Mar 2016 02:50:36 +0000
Download as text

Boot Info Script e7fc706 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 9Feb2015]

============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    197275648 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks for (,gpt10)/boot/grub.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                   /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/memtest.efi
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: FAT32
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:
```

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       iso9660
Boot sector type:  Unknown
Boot sector info: 
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb1 busy

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       vfat
Boot sector type:  FAT16
Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdb2 starts 
                   at sector 0. But according to the info from fdisk, 
                   sdb2 starts at sector 26268. According to the info in 
                   the boot sector, sdb2 has 0 sectors.
Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb1 busy
mount: /dev/sdb2 already mounted or /mnt/BootInfo/sdb2 busy

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v

BootCurrent: 0014
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0010,0011,0012,0013,0014,0015,0016,0017,0018,0019,001A,001B
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,800,fa000,b953817c-7fe7-4055-900b-257313796755)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...r................
Boot0010  Setup 
Boot0011  Boot Menu 
Boot0012* Removable Drive   030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25b20699b27e1a34f488e97534d40523c1d
Boot0013* Hard Drive    030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25bf5b01cc8ce8e9841b3a8fb94b6dfefee
Boot0014* USB Storage Device    030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25b6895f49a99882e4bb0da03ec784d2828
Boot0015* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25b3750dce1249e1748876bee5d3f25ebfb
Boot0016* Network   030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25b6567de8ee595634d842b325e6a43510b
Boot0017* Onboard NIC   030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25b1b7f7356e3475744a9a6ed8e91832083
Boot0018* Onboard NIC   030a2400d23878bc820f604d8316c068ee79d25bb4a054dda1fa7043abf832c5a88367a6
Boot0019  Diagnostics   
Boot001A  Peripheral Device setting (OPROM setting) 
Boot001B  Change boot mode setting  
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo hexdump -n 512 -C /dev/sda

00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*

000001c0  02 00 ee ff ff ff 01 00  00 00 af c2 e7 0e 00 00  |................|

000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*  

000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your Windows is a UEFI installation but you installed Kali/grub for the CSM ("legacy boot").

Try to wipe the protective MBR and let gdisk write a new one for you:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda count=1
gdisk /dev/sda
w
```

Make sure you do not miss `count=1` because if you do, `dd` will be wiping your WHOLE drive.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Grub has no been removed, when I before sudo gdisk /dev/sda said <blink>MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present</blink>  and now when I enter gdisk /dev/sda it says MBR: Protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Comment: Can you attach the output of `efibootmgr` on your post then?

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0014
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0010,0011,0012,0013,0014,0015,0016,0017,0018,0019,001A,001B
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0010  Setup
Boot0011  Boot Menu
Boot0012* Removable Drive
Boot0013* Hard Drive
Boot0014* USB Storage Device
Boot0015* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive
Boot0016* Network
Boot0017* Onboard NIC
Boot0018* Onboard NIC
Boot0019  Diagnostics
Boot001A  Peripheral Device setting (OPROM setting)
Boot001B  Change boot mode setting
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: You better put the output on your original post by editing it. Also my bad, `efibootmgr -v` instead of just `efibootmgr`.

Comment: Can you add `hexdump -n 512 -C /dev/sda` to your post as well? Maybe also compare the checksums (e.g. `md5sum`) of `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` and `/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` on the EFI system partition (`sda1`). Do you currently have Secure Boot enabled? Coz according to `efibootmgr`, Windows Boot Manager is the first active boot entry, so you should not see grub rescue.

Comment: `I can toggle this to secure and it boots straight to Windows.` By `toggle this to secure` you meant enabling Secure Boot right?

Comment: I included Hexdump, but I dont understand the commands to enter for comparing checksums (i tried sudo md5sum /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
md5sum: /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi: No such file or directory)  <br/>   . EUFI secure is off, and now Grub rescue is gone, it just says 'operating system not found.' I dont know why it doesnt just boot straight to Windows though, perhaps it's when legacy is enabled. I can toggle EUFI on and everything boots as normal (I just didn't want any residual files in the BIOS if I could help it).

Comment: Yes, EUFI Secure boot runs everything as normal, straight to Windows. Though when it's off the boot screen says 'operating system not found'. I dont know if this problem is just for me cus I've been messing around, or if any clean harddrive with Windows would boot the same (i.e. not find windows when EUFI secure is off)

Comment: Oh so your problem is actually solved (grub rescue is gone). It's normal that you cannot use CSM/legacy boot mode to boot a UEFI/GPT Windows installation. Though "Secure Boot disabled" should not be the same thing as "UEFI boot disabled". Secure Boot is not an synonym of UEFI (booting), it's just an extra bit of it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_booting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot

Comment: Thank you so much Tom, it's all pretty much new to me. Should do atleast some reading before diving straight in